# Checkbox checked attribute property not being checked if I click on it when it is unchecked state

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using bootstrap 3.4.1 and I have checkbox in each row of a table to select the employee. But If I click on the checkbox, it is not being checked. If I remove the attribute "data-chk-select-employees="@result.ID" and if the checkbox is ticked, the checkbox would be ticked. Also If I click the row, the checkbox will be ticked automatically. So I am trying to get the checkbox get ticked only when I click the checkbox and without removing "data-chk-select-employees="@result.ID"

```
<tbody>
    @if(Model.ResultList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (EmployeeListViewModel result in Model.ResultList)
        {
            <tr @(Model.ShowCheckboxes ? "data-select-employees=" + result.ID:"")>  
           @if(Model.ShowCheckboxes)
           {
                <td>
                    <div class="checkbox stylized">
                        <label>
                            <Input type="checkbox"  data-chk-select-employees="@result.ID">
                            <span class="helper"> </span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
           }
            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

If I remove the code code snippet data-chk-select-employees=@result.ID, the checkbox will work

I tried to fix by giving the code as given below but does not working either.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mainTable tr').on('click', function(e) {
    var $tr = $(this);
    var $checkbox = $('input:checkbox', this);
    
    if ($checkbox.is(e.target)) {
      // the user did not click the checkbox, so flip its state
      $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));
    }
    
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code does not look right... You are using a ternary operator but it seems to not have the second part.  Also you should use Raw method to output raw html inside the tr tag

Comment: Also I would make the input self closing